# How to look up data horizontally from vertical data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that is vertical and I am trying to use a lookup to fill a template on a second sheet. 
The template I am trying to fill out is horizontal, what would be the best formula for this problem?

I have added an example with the first image being the data set, the second image is the template I am trying to fill out.

Would I have to do two look ups? I was thinking on the template I would have to do a lookup to get all the item no.s then I would have to do a second look up to obtain all the secondary information.

[image: Sheet 1 Vertical Data]

[image: Sheet 2 horizontal Template]

Comment: A combination of one `INDEX`- and two `MATCH`-functions should be enough.

Comment: what would the two match functions be?

Answer (score 0):

Use the TRANSPOSE formula.

If your dataset is in Sheet1 occupying cells A1:D5.
In Sheet2(your template sheet) use this formula in A1:

```
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:D5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Select the range of data you want to rearrange, including any row or column labels, and press Ctrl+C.

Note: Ensure that you copy the data to do this, since using the Cut command or Ctrl+X won’t work.

2. Choose a new location in the worksheet where you want to paste the transposed table, ensuring that there is plenty of room to paste your data. The new table that you paste there will entirely overwrite any data / formatting that’s already there.
3. Right-click over the top-left cell of where you want to paste the transposed table, then choose Transpose:

[image]

4. After rotating the data successfully, you can delete the original table and the data in the new table will remain intact.